# Insert a persian text in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, persian

I want to store values of a form (in php) into mysql , one field is text and values of this field is in persian language , when I insert data to table this persian text stores in this shape : `???????`

I use these codes but it isn't work properly

```
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");   
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8_persian_ci");
```

tables ,database and columns has utf8_persian_ci collation

Comment: duplicated search utf 8 there are tons of questions

Comment: Try adding `iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");` to the top of your script.

Comment: Make sure your table columns use correct encodings too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure the collation is utf8. collation persiab case insensitive may not work properly as the input char code may not be in range of persian charachters. unicode 8 will work. change the collation to utf8_general

Answer (score 2):

your column/table has wrong coding, they should have

utf8_persian_ci

too

Comment: my database,tables and column is utf8_persian_ci collation

Comment: Can I have English strings as well?