# android Post UTF-8 with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, post, server, persian

i'm using below code to exchange data between android and server but i'm in trouble with sending Persian characters(UTF-8). In server side the received datas looks something like `Ù…Ø­ØªÙˆØ§ Ù†Ø§Ù…Ù†Ø§Ø³Ø¨`

Code:

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        if (args != null) {
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            String query = args.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
```

Comment: i think the problem is with server side. they have to decode the string int utf-8 format before insert into database.

Comment: @Nas so what is solution ?

Comment: what type of platform u r using in back end php r .net r someother

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14117250/1790537) may be help u to insert the persian text in correct form

Comment: @Nas Thanks but not solved and i think the problem is in android code not server , because with old method (Apache library) everything is OK

Comment: please post your solution as answer so others can know if they have similar problem.

Comment: @Nas no buddy , i don't want to use Apache method . my problem and question is still remains